Conformal mapping concerning a branch cut

Map the region $\Omega = \{z=re^{i \theta} \in \mathbb{C}: r >0, \frac{\pi}{4} < \theta < \frac{7\pi}{4}  \} \setminus [-1,0]$ onto $\mathbb{H}$.

Thus, the $\Omega$ is the complex plane with the wedge from $- \pi/4$ to $\pi/4$ removed and the slit $[-1,0]$ removed as well.
First, the map $T_1(z) = z^2$ sends the ray with arguments of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to the ray with arguments $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the ray with arguments $\frac{-\pi}{4}$ to the ray with arguments $- \frac{\pi}{2}$ and this inverts the slit from $[-1,0]$ to $[0,1]$. The map $T_2(z) = -iz$ rotates the region to the upper half plane and now the slit is on the imaginary axis between $0$ and $-i$. Now, it remains to collapse the slit to the upper half plane. The map $T_3(z) = \sqrt{z^2+1}$ will keep the upper half plane fixed and then $-i$ gets mapped to $0$ while every point on the imaginary axis $\alpha i$ for $ 0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$ will necessarily have $\sqrt{(\alpha i)^2+1} = \sqrt{1-\alpha^2} > 0$ and so gets mapped to the positive real axis.
But I must be concerned about my choice for $T_1(z)=z^2$. For if we interpret the ray in the fourth quadrant as having argument $\frac{7 \pi}{4}$, then such a ray actually gets mapped to the ray having argument $\frac{7\pi}{2} > 2\pi$. If interpreted in this way, does this ruin the geometry behind the composition of conformal maps? I've never been good at understanding the concept of branch cuts $-$ so if someone could explain to me in this context how to understand the implementation of branch cuts here, that would be great!
For example, if I wanted to take $T_1(z)=z^2$ in such a way so that the ray in the fourth quadrant is interpreted as having argument $- \frac{\pi}{4}$ rather than argument $\frac{7\pi}{4}$, in words, what would I say?

READ ME: I understand that the problem at the top is worded in such a way so that it appears that the arguments are fixed as $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{7 \pi }{4}$. This is merely how I chose to describe the geoemtric appearance of $\Omega$ since, in general, posting unnecessary/messy images on MSE is discouraged.

$T_(z) = z^2$ is not injective in $\Omega$, so that can not be the first step in mapping $\Omega$ conformally onto $\Bbb H$.
I would start with a rotation by $e^{-i\pi/4}$, which maps $\Omega$ onto the union of the first three quadrants with the segment from $e^{i3\pi/4}$ to $0$ removed. Then continue with an exponentiation which increases the opening angle of the sector from $3 \pi/2$ to $2\pi$, that is
$$
  z \mapsto z^{4/3} = |z|^{4/3} \cdot \exp\left(i\frac 43 \arg z\right)
$$
where $\arg z$ is chosen in the range $(0, 3 \pi/ 2)$. That maps the previous domain onto the entire plane with the ray $[-1, +\infty)$ removed.
The rest is standard: A translation by $+1$, then take the square root.

I'm having a hard time understanding why the second map removes the ray $[-1, \infty)$. Surely, I can see that $e^{i 3\pi /4}$ gets mapped to $-1$ but could you explain which other points get mapped to the $[-1, \infty)$ ray?

@GrigorHakobyan:  The “three quadrants” are mapped to the plane without the positive real axis, and  the segment from $e^{i 3\pi /4}$ to $0$ is mapped to the segment from $-1$ to $0$, because $z \mapsto z^{4/3}$ multiplies the argument with $4/3$. So the image after the second map is the plane without $[-1, 0]$ and without the positive real axis.

Okay, I agree with all this now. We translate right $1$ to get $-1 \mapsto 0$. Now, we have the plane with the positive real axis (and $0$) removed. Taking the square root should take the ray along the underside of the positive real axis and open it up from $2\pi$ to just $\pi$, yielding the upper half plane. What need is there for a final rotation?

@GrigorHakobyan: There is no need :)

Thanks for your assistance! I edited your first map since your first rotation as originally written ($e^{i \pi /4}$) implied a counterclockwise rotation. I made the argument negative to make the rotation clockwise
